# Idea doesn't show error message if functional interface has multiple non default methods

Tags: intellij-idea, java-8, functional-interface

I use idea 12.
And see following result after compilation.
[image]

I am wondering that idea doesn't show error in text editor.

Is it idea bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what kind of support IntelliJ IDEA 12 has for Java 8 inspections and code analysis, but in IntelliJ 14 this works fine. However the error is displayed only if you have Project language level set to 8 in Project structure (which makes sense).

So try changing the language level if you haven't done so already. If that doesn't help then it's possible that IntelliJ 12 doesn't support this.

Comment: You're right, version 12 has poor support for Java 8, it was improved significantly in 13 and 14.

Comment: language level is java 8.